# AWS Codepipeline Example

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-cloudformation

I am trying the example of Codepipeline for Lambda Function given by AWS. On executing the pipeline its getting failed during cloudformation execution with error saying "Template configuration is not valid"

Below is the template I copied from the example but its failing any suggestions?

AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Outputs the time
Resources:
  TimeFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs6.10
      CodeUri: ./
      Events:
        MyTimeApi:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /TimeResource
            Method: GET

Also please let me know where could I see the detailed error log?

Comment: Could you post a link to the example please?

Comment: I am following the below mentioned example http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.html

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think the question is straight forward the example given in AWS docs in the link docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/automating-deployment.h‌​tml isn't working for me and the problem I am facing is described in initial post. I am getting the Template Not Valied error . Please let me know if problem is still not clear.

Comment: @Raf It's pretty obvious what the desired behavior is, the problem is specific, and I can try and reproduce from the docs.

Comment: @Rohit could you replace your template example with formatted code, if you edit your post, remove that bit and then cut and paste the one you have, if you then select all the text and select code from the little menu bar at the top it should format your JSON properly. Note use YOUR code not the example stuff please. Also you can go to CloudWatch and view logs for your lambda function.

Comment: Totally agree with @Raf I still think it is missing required info to get help by someone